# Is a parallelogram with equal sides necessarily a rhombus? Is one with 4 right angles (or congruent diagonals) necessarily a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, rectangles, quadrilateral

We know that a rhombus is a parallelogram that has 1) equal sides and 2) diagonals that are perpendicular to each other. If, for instance, we are a told that a figure is a parallelogram and that it has perpendicular diagonals we automatically know that it is a rhombus, id est, we know all its sides are equal.

> If we are told that a parallelogram has all sides equal, we know is a rhombus?

On the other hand, we know a rectangle is a parallelogram that satisfies 1) all angles equal to 90° and 2) diagonals that are congruent (i.e. equal diagonals).

> If we are told that a parallelogram has 4 right angles, or similarly, that a parallelogram has congruent diagonals, can we conclude immediately that it is a rectangle?
>
> To sum up: four sides equal in a parallelogram is equivalent to perpendicular diagonals and, likewise, four right angles in a parallelogram equivalent to congruent diagonals?

Comment: I'd have thought that the **definition** of a rhombus was as an equilateral quadrilateral.

Comment: You appear to be saying that A rhombus is a quadrilateral with three properties: (1)  it is a parallelogram, (2) all sides have equal length, and (3) the diagonals are orthogonal.  AND that any two of those imply the third.  Is that correct?

Comment: please specify what you want,your question is very unclear to me.

Comment: Quadrilateral with orthogonal diagonals are called "kites". Rhombuses have the definition of four equal side lengths only.

Answer (score 1):

You should be clear with the definitions.Definition of parallelogram is a quadrilateral whose opposite sides are parallel.Rhombus is defined to be a quadrilateral with 4 equal sides.Now we can prove that in a parallelogram,the opposite sides have equal length.Now if 2 adjascent sides of a parallelogram are equal,then it has to be a rhombus as per the definition.Rectangle is defined to be a parallelogram with one of its angles a right angle.And square is defined as a rectangle whose adjoining sides are equal.You may find help from the book
Euclidean geometry a first course-A Solomonovich.And please specify your doubts in the question.

Comment: I think what OP really wants is a proof that equal sides implies perpendicular diagonals, and that four right angles is equivalent to congruent diagonals.

Comment: I think it can be found in any of the elementary geometry books.

Comment: I'm sure it can be. But StackExchange would like to become a repository of such useful knowledge. Also, OP might need help understanding what's in the textbooks.

Comment: Ok I shall make an edit...

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly the OP is looking for.

Comment: It is advisable not to answer until the OP has clarified their question. If the question is changed, although you can still keep it, your answer will not be useful to people reading this question.

Comment: I will edit the answer accordingly.I would not answer but I thought the OP wants what I answered.